# Can't access TempData during ajax request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

Why we are unable to access TempData during ajax request.

Controller:

```
TempData["MytempData"] = MyMessage;
return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

View:

```
$.ajax(
{
type: 'POST',
success: function (result) {
value=TempData["MytempData"];//why this is not possible
},
});
```

Also I know that i can access this data using json object ,as following

```
return Json(new {isSucess=true,Message=MyMessage},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

but my question is not about how should i pass data from controller to view.I just want to know the reason that why we are unable to access the TempData during ajax request.

Comment: You're confusing Javascript code and C# code.

Comment: @SLaks 1.when we reload the whole page then tempdata line is executed 2. when the ajax request is sent the tempdata line is also executed on server side.The tempdata line is executed in both cases .we get the value in first case but not in second case.Why?

Comment: `TempData` doesn't exist in the first place in JS code.  You need to send and read the HTTP response.

Comment: Razor code is evaluated on the server before its sent to the client. The value of `var value` will be what ever the initial value of `TempData["MytempData"]` was. Unless you send a new value to the client in the ajax call, it never changes because the page is not reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The razor compiler will view `value=TempData["MytempData"]` as javascript and will not try to compile it as C#. To tell razor that it is C# you need to prepend `@`

```
$.ajax(
{
type: 'POST',
success: function (result) {
value=@TempData["MytempData"];//Should work now.
},
});
```

but bear in mind that will be of type `object` so you may wish to cast it as well.